# Find package and activity names of system apps?

Tags: android, android-activity, package

How would I go about finding the package names and main activity name for system apps on motoblur and touchwiz? I am making an app but I want it to be universal, not just Sense and stock android. I dont actually own a phone running touchwiz or motoblur so I am stumped on how to find them out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you should not start activities via package/class names - system apps vary from device to device AND activity class names might change with app updates (I noticed Google Maps did this once).

The other reason would be that users might prefer to use some other app they installed to do particular task (for example I prefer to take pictures with a 3rd party app).

You should invoke apps via system defined intents.

Comment: Thanks, I'm fairly new at all this so what code would I use to do that? Or is there a link you could provide? Any help is appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to gather info about installed apps on the phone than go through the `list` and search for desired  activity

```
   PackageManager packmngr = this.getPackageManager(); 
    Intent ints = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null)
    ints.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER); 
    List<ResolveInfo> list = packmngr.queryIntentActivities(ints, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
```

`ints.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);`   <--- Here you can specify what type of `Intent` (which the developer of the other app defined in the manifest) to search with the query, it can by either `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER` or `CATEGORY_DEFAULT`, actually the main activities are of type `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER`.

And the trivial iteration in the list:

```
       for(ResolveInfo rlnfo: list)
        {
             //Adjust the code and do tests within here.
            Log.i("ACTIVITY INFO: ", rlnfo.activityInfo.toString());
            Log.i("ACTIVITY NAME: ",rlnfo.resolvePackageName.toString());
        }
```

Check here for more info about constants and methods:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html